# Nginx rewrite subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm trying to do a rewrite for nginx. It's working but for sub directories it is taking the root's index.php instead of the index.php in the individual subdir. This is how my directory structure looks like:

```
/index.php
/p/index.php
/c/index.php
```

and this is my rewrite:

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
  rewrite ^/([^./]+)/?$ /index.php?act=$1 break; #need break?
  rewrite ^/([^./]+)/(.+)/?$ /index.php?act=$1&upm=$2 break;
  rewrite ^/([^./]+)/([^./]+)/?$ /$1/index.php?act=$2;
}
```

I tried adding an entry for each subdirectory but it doesn't work either:

```
  location /p/ {
        root /home/user/public_html/p/;
        rewrite ^/([^./]+)/(.+)/?$ /index.php?act=$1&upm=$2 break;
  }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `rewrite ^/([^./]+)/([^./]+)/?$ /$1/index.php?act=$2;` will never be executed as the previous rewrite will always match. You might try swapping rewrites #2 and #3.

The `root /home/user/public_html/p/;` is probably wrong as `/p/` will appear twice as it is in the `$document_root` and the `$uri`.

The `rewrite` in your `location /p/` should rewrite to `/p/index.php` and not `/index.php`?